# Java enum-based factory to calculate entry parameters

Tags: java, enum, factory-method

I want to create a factory to return all Source instances that match given entry parameters- that is, I want to iterate through some Collection of objects and for each entry check boolean method.
I thought about enum, as  I'm guaranteed to iterate through them all.
I came up with something like this:

simple interface

```
public interface Source {

    public boolean isPresent(SourceCalculationData data);

    public Source2 getType();
}
```

my take on enum factory:

```
public enum Source2 {

    IB("IB", SourceIb.class),
    CCWEW("BOT", SourceCcwew.class),
    OBD("CUF", SourceCuf.class),
    PB("PB", SourcePb.class),
    COK("COK", SourceCok.class),
    CCZEW("CCZ", SourceCczew.class),
    CRM("CRM", SourceCrm.class),
    APP("APP", SourceApp.class);

    private static final Logger SENSITIVE_LOGGER = SensitiveLoggerFactory.getSensitiveLogger(Source2.class);

    private String configChannel;

    private Class<? extends Source> clazz;

    private Source2(String configChannel, Class<? extends Source> clazz) {
        this.configChannel = configChannel;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<? extends Source> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public String getConfigChannel() {
        return configChannel;
    }

    public Source getSource() {
        return getAction(clazz);
    }

    private Source getAction(Class<? extends Source> source2Class) {

        try {
            return source2Class.newInstance();

        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            SENSITIVE_LOGGER.warn("<< Exception occured during init of {}, returning unkown source.", source2Class);
            return new SourceUnkown();
        }

    }
```

and use case:

```
        final SourceCalculationData data = new SourceCalculationData();

        final EnumSet<Source2> presentSources = EnumSet.noneOf(Source2.class);
        for (final Source2 source2ToCheck : Source2.values()) {
            if (source2ToCheck.getSource().isPresent(data)) presentSources.add(source2ToCheck);
        }
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the best code in the world. Any suggestions what will make it better?

Comment: Greetings & Salutations, to prevent this from being closed; I would take out the implementation of `SourceIb`, since we don't review stubs. Ideally you would also figure out your logging and error handling before submitting the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is good, but I would suggest following points to improve:

1. It is really hard to test/mock `source2ToCheck.getSource()`.
2. `Source2` contains a lot logic/functionality (it is source type and
   factory) it has to be simplified.
3. `getSource()` creates new course
   object it is confusing
4. `getSource(...)` calls `getAction(...)` that create a source object. It is wired.
5. Be aware `source2Class.newInstance()` is deprecated since java 9
   `source2Class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`

***Suggestions:***

- I would propose to create dedicated interface/class for source factory
- Rename `Source2` to `SourceType`.
- Throw custom exception `CustomCantCreateSourceException` instead of `return new SourceUnkown()`. Because it is real exceptional situation.
- Remove public methods modifier from Source interface
- Minor enhancements you can find in following code

*Source Factory interface:*

```
public interface SourceFactory {
    Source create(SourceType type);
}
```

*Factory implementation:*

```
public class SourceFactoryImpl implements SourceFactory {
    @Override
    public Source create(SourceType type) {
            try {
                return type.getClazz().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                    | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                SENSITIVE_LOGGER.warn("<< Exception occured during init of {}, returning unkown source.", source2Class);
                throw new CustomCantCreateSourceException();
            }
    }
}
```

*Renamed Source2:*

```
public enum SourceType {

    IB("IB", SourceIb.class),
    CCWEW("BOT", SourceCcwew.class),
    OBD("CUF", SourceCuf.class),
    PB("PB", SourcePb.class),
    COK("COK", SourceCok.class),
    CCZEW("CCZ", SourceCczew.class),
    CRM("CRM", SourceCrm.class),
    APP("APP", SourceApp.class);

    private static final Logger SENSITIVE_LOGGER = SensitiveLoggerFactory.getSensitiveLogger(SourceType.class);

    private String configChannel;

    private Class<? extends Source> clazz;

    private SourceType(String configChannel, Class<? extends Source> clazz) {
        this.configChannel = configChannel;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<? extends Source> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public String getConfigChannel() {
        return configChannel;
    }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
public class SourceService {
    private final SourceFactory factory;

    public SourceService(SourceFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public EnumSet<SourceType> fillSources() {
        final SourceCalculationData data = new SourceCalculationData();

        final EnumSet<SourceType> presentSources = EnumSet.noneOf(SourceType.class);
        for (final SourceType source2ToCheck : SourceType.values()) {
            if (factory.create(source2ToCheck).isPresent(data)) {
                presentSources.add(source2ToCheck);
            }
        }
        return presentSources;
    }
}
```